# Delayed loading of css on page refresh (Webpack)

Tags: css, webpack, load, delay

I have splitted webpack configurations, common, development and production configs. I load also jQuery via webpack. The problem is that, on page refresh, there is short delay for about 200-300ms before css is loaded, so my page is firstly shown without it, and then reloads with css. What could be the problem?

In common, under plugins, I have:

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
  }),
```

In development config I have:

```
{
            test: /\.scss$|\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "style-loader",
                    options: {sourceMap: true}
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {sourceMap: true}
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {sourceMap: true}
                }
            ]
        },
```

and for production mode:

```js
optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJSPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
                uglifyOptions: {
                    mangle: false,
                    compress: {
                        inline: false
                    }
                }
            }),

            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
                cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
                cssProcessorOptions: {parser: _safe, discardComments: {removeAll: true}},
                canPrint: true
            })
        ]
    },


module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT** 
Here is compiled html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=app></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js?32313079e3d03749d814"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide compiled .html file?

Comment: you should not apply `sass-loader` to css files. Separate the configurations for each.

Comment: You mean, for `.css` files, apply `style-loader` and `css-loader` and for `.scss` files, apply `sass-loader` ?

Comment: for scss apply `style-loader`, `css-loader` and `sass-loader`. For css you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is too late to answer this question, however, that is not related to Webpack. You have attached your bundle at the end of the page. Therefore before loading the bundle the page content comes up and after that bundles loaded the style. Therefore until it loads the completely there is a little time that takes time for the browser to run the bundle and attach the style. It can be fixed by putting the bundle in the `<head>` tag. You may need to run your jquery codes inside `$(document).ready()` function by passing a callback as an argument. Pay attention that it can affect the load time of your page as well.

Another solution can be configuring Webpack to load the styles first and then your js codes.

Comment: I ended up using [`MiniCssExtractPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#recommend) in my webpack config to separate my CSS from my JS so that I could put the CSS in the `<head>` and the JS in the `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be to hide body:

`<body style="display:none">`

And then make it visible after you load your JS(i.e: inside your fetch):

`document.body.style.display = 'block';`